# I asked a recruiter to choose a meeting time, and he hasn't responded. How should I follow up?

Tags: job-search, recruitment, email

I sent a cold mail to a potential recruiter. He replied saying he'd like to talk to me in the coming week. I replied suggesting I would make myself available at any time he is fine with. The week is almost over and I have not received any further communication from him.

Should I send him a reminder? What should I say?

Comment: Similar: [How should I deal with an employer who doesn't honor a phone interview time?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/19544)

Answer (score 8):

As a person with experience in staffing, recruiting, and as a busy career coach that frequently schedules clients, I have this specific bit of help; giving your availability in a more focused way can sometimes yield better results. Instead of thinking "oh I can reach them any time" and then moving on - possibly to forget you, they will check their schedule and figure out if they can fit you in.  If they can't do those times, they are likely to pitch an alternative time. I frequently also add a variety of contact methods for convenience.

Here's an example message you could send:

> I'm sorry we didn't connect this week.  I am still interested in <whatever specific functional area and geographical area (or any other relevant details)>. I am available at <2 or so times/dates you are available>. The best number to reach me by is <555-555-5555> and I'm available by facetime or skype <your skype id> as well.
>   Thank you for your time,

Answer (score 1):

## When one method of communication fails, try another one

You've tried sending an email but it didn't have the desired result. If you're still intent on achieving your goal, you should try a different method of communication, in this case most likely a phone call.

> [Greeting], this is [user82123] calling. Last week you sent me an email to say that you'd like to have a more in-depth conversation, when would be convenient for you to do that?

With a little luck, the answer might even be something like "Hey, thanks for calling, in fact I have some free time right now if that works for you" and you can get the whole thing wrapped up right there and then!

This concept is one to remember for any point in your professional career: don't keep using the same method of communication over and over again, if one doesn't seem to be achieving the desired result, try a different one. This usually means starting with chat/email, then working up to a phone call, and then just going to the other person physically.