# Interviewer never called. What do I do?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing

I had a scheduled phone interview for 2:00PM. The employer emailed me directly after I sent them my resume a few days prior. I gave him the number for him to call after he requested it, and he even sent me a Google Calendar Event which I confired.

Note that all this occurred 1 day before the scheduled interview!

But the next day came and went. I made sure my phone was on and ready, I rechecked the date and number for him to call. Everything was right but he just didn't call. He never even emailed me about the missed interview. I myself felt reluctant to email him about it, so I didn't - for two whole weeks!

I'm curious why he didn't call and if there's a way to reschedule the interview. But I don't know if I'm right to contact him again after two weeks.

Comment: Two weeks?! I would have sent an email after 15 minutes. You should *definitely* make an attempt to contact them, but two weeks is an awfully long time. The position might be filled by now.

Comment: You don't really have anything to lose by contacting them now, but I would not have high hopes. Let this be a learning experience. Interviewers often just plain forget. Maybe they found someone else. There's no way to know unless you contact them.

Comment: Very related (duplicate?) - http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/1391/2322

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Yes.**

Two weeks is plenty long enough to wait before contacting the interviewer. You should definitely follow up with the interviewer and see if he is still interested in conducting the interview.

I had this happen once, and I e-mailed the interviewer about a half-hour after the scheduled time. I received a reply stating that he had gotten stuck in a meeting with management. We rescheduled for another day, and there were no issues.

Given this experience, I would suggest that if it happens again (either with the same person or on future interviews with other companies), that you actually contact them within the appointment window that you were scheduled, or at least the same day.

Interviewers should expect to be held to the same standard as the interviewee, including punctuality. If you contact someone after they missed an appointment and they get mad or hold it against you, they're probably not a person you would want to work for anyway.