# Manager attempts to schedule first interview, but never responds

Tags: interviewing

Yesterday, I got an email from someone at a company that I applied to. Almost an hour after applying. They said they were interested in phone interviewing me "later this week." I responded to their email and sent over my availability. Come today I have not received a response which is peculiar to me. If they don't respond by tomorrow afternoon or Friday should I ping them or just forget about the opportunity?

Comment: It never hurts to contact them, but be aware that the odds aren't great of anything happening.

Comment: You think that because its been a day and will be two days tomorrow my app has likely been discarded?

Comment: I think that if an organization can't manage communication through the recruitment process that there are implications for how well they can manage their staff and workload.  Contact them tomorrow afternoon if you haven't heard anything by then.

Comment: No because I have not had any interviews. This question is asking about handling communication prior to first interview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, contact the company again.

Preparing for an interview takes time. It could be that the interviewer needs to free a time slot in what could be a very busy schedule. Or it could be that the interviewer is preparing a set of questions to ask you. Honestly, there could be thousands of reasons as to why the company hasn't responded to you yet, it's your job to find out, professionally, in a follow up email.

Something along the lines of:

> Good afternoon,
>
> I was contacted by X who was wanting a phone interview with me. We are still in the stages of scheduling the interview and was wanting to know if the decision on a time slot has been made?
>
> My available times are listed below:
>
> ...

Make sure to include your availability again and make sure you are actually available on those days, otherwise you both could end up with some difficulties<sup>1</sup>.

They obviously think you're a good candidate, I mean, you were contacted *a mere hour* later after applying. To show them that you are an even better candidate, let them that know that you are definitely interested in the job with some follow up communication.

It's always best to ask questions and learn more than to stay in ignorance, even if the questions sound daft to you.

1. [Should I follow up with an interviewer who did not call at the scheduled time?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1391/should-i-follow-up-with-an-interviewer-who-did-not-call-at-the-scheduled-time)

Comment: If you are going to contact them before the end of the week you might also provide availability for the next week. It's possible the company got swamped with some issue (or applications) and it's possible you were bumped from the short list. Providing availability for next week since you haven't heard is proactive and not demanding.